# Uso do “em que” na frase abaixo

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

> Os filmes são paralelamente escritos para homens “presos” nesses
> cenários **em que** são miseráveis porque não possuem profundidade
> emocional, de modo que ficam prostrados em rotinas de imersão
> cultural.

O “em que” está sendo usado corretamente? Normalmente vejo o “em que são” acompanhado de verbos no particípio. Abaixo faço uma alteração:

*“Os filmes são paralelamente escritos para homens “presos” nesses cenários em que são miserabilizados”*

O que acham?

Comment: A frase não é talvez um exemplo de claridade, mas não há nada de errado com o "em que".

Comment: Sinceramente, nunca nem pensei que “em que” deveria estar com verbo no particípio e duvido disso também. A frase com “em que” diz algo como “NESSES CENÁRIOS, os homens presos são miseráveis”; sem “em”, diz que “ESSES CENÁRIOS são miseráveis”.